# Cannot find DatastoreManager even though it's among the dependencies

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

So I'm trying to write an GAE application with JDO. The problem is that even though it appears I already have all the required dependencies in my pom.xml and when I search for com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager in my IDE, I can actually find it, my application throws an exception on startup

> org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class
>   "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager" was not found in
>   the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.

here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>livefun</artifactId>
        <groupId>fi.livefun</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>fi.livefun</groupId>
    <artifactId>livefun-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
           ** MODULE DEPENDENCIES
       ** ********************************************************************** -->


        <!-- **********************************************************************
           ** GOOGLE APP ENGINE DEPENDIENCIES
       ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **                 SPRING DEPENDENCIES                              **
             ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **                 PERSISTENCE DEPENDENCIES                             **
             ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **                 GENERAL DEPENDENCIES                             **
             ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **                 OTHER DEPENDENCIES                               **
             ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
            ** TEST DEPENDENCIES
        ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml>
                    <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate>
                    <showGenerated>true</showGenerated>
                    <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp/</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>false</fork>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I know this is old but I'm trying to revive an old app and I'm running into the exact same issue. Has anyone ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error when you deploy your app to App Engine, it means that you did not include the required jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. It's not enough to have it on your classpath - you also need to make it available to your app running on the App Engine.

If you use Eclipse, select your project and look at the Problems tab. There may be a warning there that a resource is not available on a server. Right click on it and select "Copy..." option. Or find this jar and copy it to this folder manually.

Comment: actually I'm using Intellij Idea 14 Ultimate.

Comment: also my maven dependencies do not have the scope "provided", hence I really don't think I need to copy anything manually. All the libs are just added to the war file based on my pom.xml, right?

Comment: I unzipped the war. The class that it complains about is in the right place in the project (imported from dependency)